# making an unordered list on a page that already has a navigation bar

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am making a webpage for a college project.

I have a navigation bar made with an unordered list and css, and i cannot figure out how to create a bulleted list on that page without it also going into the nav bar.

I am new to programming and html in general.

**HTML**

```
  <ul> 
    <li>
       <a href="tkhome.html">Home</a>
    </li> 
     <li><a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a></li> <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
     <li><a href="imagepage.html">Image Gallery</a></li> 
  </ul>
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Seems to me you are applying CSS to ALL `ul` elements by writing something like this `ul {list-style:none}` instead of `nav ul {list-style:none;}`

Comment: HTML<ul>
  <li><a href="tkhome.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="imagepage.html">Image Gallery</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Yes i am applying the CSS to all UL elements, that is where my problem is orignating

Comment: Sorry, i am not even sure how to post code properly on SO. lol

Comment: Well then, be specific about which UL get that styling, like in the example I wrote. Also, add the code to your question directly (edit it) instead of posting code as comment.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will try that right now. When i posted the code in the original post it came up as a bulleted list lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your menu html tags to `<nav> <ul>` so that it looks something like this...

```
<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Then apply your menus CSS to that style set only i.e.

```
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Now you can create your bullet point list normally on the same page without conflict. i.e.

```
<ul>
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

If you've found it helpful please mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a bulleted list, use the unordered list tags `<ul></ul>` and list item `<li></li>` tags as shown in the example below.

```
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example2</li>
<li>Example3</li>
</ul>
```

The above example would create a bulleted list as shown below.

- Example
- Example2
- Example3

If you wanted to change this list to an ordered list (numbered list), change the `<ul></ul>` tags to `<ol></ol>`, as shown in the example below.

```
<ol>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example2</li>
<li>Example3</li>
</ol>
```

The above example would create a numbered list as shown below.

1.Example
2.Example2
3.Example3

If you wanted to apply CSS style or use an image as your bullet list, create CSS code similar to the example below.

```
#content ul li 
{
list-style-Type: none;
padding: 0 0 4px 23px;
background: url(http no-repeat left top;
}
```

In this example, using an external .css file, we're telling the web page to only change the bulleted items in the `<div id="content"></div>` section. If you want all bulleted items to change, you can remove the #content in the above example. In the second line, the `list-style-Type: none;` tells the browser to display no bullets. In the third line, the `padding: 0 0 4px 23px;` is the padding and indent around the bullets. Finally, the last background line tells the browser to use an image as the bullet and where to display it. With this CSS code, we get bullets as shown below.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have gotten it to load correctly using this technique, but not sure i used it correctly.

Comment: I used: <ul id="nav"> as the start tag and used #nav in the css. Will this validate?

Comment: @Siodinn yes you can do it like that `#nav { ... }`

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. Really appreciate the help. Nervous for JS bc even HTML5 is confusing me! lol. Thanks again

Comment: I don't think you deserved a downvote. It's always difficult to use the mark up of this editor. This line seems to be a typo `background: url(http no-repeat left top;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `class` or `id` from your CSS. E.g.

```
.nonbulletnav {

  list-style-type: none;

}
```

Or

```
#nonbulletnav {

  list-style-type: none;

}
```

Then in your html code just give that `class` or `id` to `<ul>` element as:

```
<ul class="nonbulletnav">

....
....

</ul>
```

---

`list-style-type` is an important attribute. With this you can style the bullets in different ways like use square instead of circular bullets. You can read [about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type). As it is obvious `list-style-type: none` takes off the bullets and indents the list element properly.